# docker0 vs eth0 when gaining remote access to ubuntu desktop?

Tags: linux, networking, macos, ubuntu, remote-desktop

I’m trying to get remote access with screen sharing to my Ubuntu PC from my Mac. I need to be able to connect to it over the internet from another network. When I go `finder>go>connect to server` on my Mac and enter `<ip-address>:5900` I get [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quq80.png)

It says:

```
Connection failed to <ip-address>

Unable to communicate with <ip-address>. Make sure the remote computer 
is available and the firewall is not blocking screen sharing.
```

The thing is I'm not sure if I'm putting in the right IP address because when I run `ifconfig` I don't get any responses that say `eth0`, only `docker0`, `enp4s0`, and `lo`

I've been using the `docker0` inet address, is this what I should be using? If not, how can I find the `eth0` address?

Let me know if I need to post more information.

Thank You

Comment: `enp4s0` is your ethernet device; your system is using [Predictable Network Interface names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/).  `eth0` is considered an unpredictable name.

Comment: `ping` and `tracert` can be informative.  So could the routing table.

Comment: @quixotic That IP address works when I'm on the same network, do you know how I can do this from an outside network across the internet?

Comment: you're probably using NAT on the local network; you'll have to setup the router to forward the necessary ports to the ubuntu system, and then you'd connect the mac to the router's external IP.  see https://superuser.com/q/603831/685512 https://superuser.com/q/106688/685512 (and many many other versions of the same question)