# Accessing computers in a remote location

Tags: networking, ssh

I apologize for the basic nature of this question, but I would appreciate if I can get a chance to learn. It is about accessing remote computers:

**Situation**

I have three or four computers at home. (windows, linux, mac, etc). I use internet from a provider so each of these machines have a IP. (I suppose it is an internal "private" IP)

So, lets say, computer A has IP A , so I can do `ssh  theuser@IP_A` from computer B and access the computer (not graphically, just terminal).
I can also use visual studio code and access A remotely from B or C. No problem there.

Let's say I go with my PC A to my office (in which I can connect from a different network) or to a cafe that provides internet , and I want to ssh my -say- linux computer B.  How can I do that?

In that case, I am pretty sure private IPs won't do so what is the way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect home computers (Linux) from office computer (windows) using putty](https://superuser.com/questions/603831/how-to-connect-home-computers-linux-from-office-computer-windows-using-putty)

Comment: "Let's say I go with my PC A to my office (in which I can connect from a different network) or to a cafe that provides internet "   <-- I have done this (and can do this) using a Router in my home office that allows secure entry from anywhere I happen to be. I use remote access software on my roaming laptop.

Comment: The first step is to have at least one "public" IP, either by your ISP (some ISPs still give you public IPs by default, some have a more expensive contract for businesses which include public IPs), or by some cloud provider. This will cost you money. Once you have that, you can set up routers etc. so accessing computer B via this public IP works. Details depend on how you got your public IP.

Comment: @dirkt so I have to ask my provider , or is there a way to check the configuration of my network to see if there is a public IP?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Not really. The answer that Darius gave started good (so I have to know the external IP-- *How??*) but I was lost after that. The other answers were no good.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 kinds of technologies for this task. (Within a scope of a single answer, I can only give an overview of them.)

#### 1. [Port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)

Your home computers have [private IPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) -- but the router that they are connected to the Internet through likely has a public IP on its external interface (that's true for most home Internet providers). If you find out this address in you router's configuration interface, you can connect to it from the Internet.

Then, it's possible to configure a router to forward all incoming connections to its external interface with a certain protocol and [port number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)) to a certain internal IP and port. This feature is typically called "port forwarding", "port mapping" or "virtual server" in router interfaces.

Some routers allow to specify the internal machine by name, but most require to specify its IP address -- so you'd have to also make that machine's IP address "static" in the router's DHCP settings so that it doesn't change and the forwarding rule remains valid.

Then you can connect to the specific port on your specific internal machine from the Internet by connecting to `<your router's IP>:<forwarded port>`.

For most providers, the router's public IP address is dynamic (may change on each startup and/or from time to time) and Internet providers typically charge extra for a static IP. You can skirt around that by using DDNS (a third-party DNS service with an ability to easily update its records with authentication which your router will do automatically whenever its public IP changes) -- those however also typically come at a cost and your router needs to support the specific DDNS provider to update the record since there are no standards for the update protocol.

#### 2. [Virtual Private Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network)

The scenario you're describing is what VPN was originally created for (hence the name); being able to provide authenticated Internet access with it that seems to be its primary use case now is but a fortunate side effect.

Upon connecting to a VPN server, a VPN client creates a virtual network adapter at your local machine with an IP from the remote network. Through it, you can access machines on the remote network in the same way as if you physically were on that network.
The VPN client encapsulates packets sent to the virtual adapter into a so-called "tunneling protocol" and sends them to the VPN server which unpacks them and sends to the target machines on the remote network -- and vice versa.

This is a very simple technique so there are lots of VPN implementations -- even SSH provides its own, the "SSH tunnel". The ease of setup and use and OS support varies wildly though. Current open standards are listed at the Wikipedia page linked to above and in e.g. https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/vpn/start

VPN server support in routers is not very common, so you'd probably need to shop for a "VPN router" or install OpenWRT onto yours [if it supports the hardware](https://openwrt.org/supported_devices). You can also run a VPN server on one of the internal machines -- then you'd need to port-forward it as per above and keep it powered on whenever you need access which is an inconvenience. In any case, you need to have and know the router's public IP to connect to like above.

#### 3. Remote access through an intermediary

As you can see, the main problem with connecting is to have to have a public IP -- if you don't, there's nowhere to connect to.
However, if there's a 3rd-party server with a public IP, both your machines can connect to it and talk with each other through those established connections.

Most online "Remote access" services work like this, and they are virtually always paid due to the maintenance costs for the intermediary servers (they need to support the combined bandwidth of all the forwarded connections). For those few that are free, you'll likely get very poor connectivity due to limited server resources.

Since the intermediary is a general-purpose communication channel, such services typically offer multiple types of connectivity in their clients: remote desktop, file transfer, VPN etc.

The key upside is that you don't need to have a machine with a known public IP.
The key downside is the cost, and the fact that there are next to no open standards in real use so your options would be limited to whatever functions and integrations the specific service's client supports.

Comment: Note that an increasing number of ISPs use [carrier grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) for non-business contracts, which means your router doesn't get a dynamic public IP.